# iphone-inapp purchase

Tags: ios

Im doing project on ipad application regarding in-app purchase for downloading audio from audio store which is included in my application. I put all the audio files for free download. My Question is "Is there any necessity to include in-app purchase for free audio download?"

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand: You **dont** need to enable In-App purchase for your free content since there is nothing to purchase. Enabling it takes addition work and resource, so use it only when required.